# how to get all text of html file inside two specific keywords

Tags: php, html, regex, simple-html-dom

I have a html file and two keywords and i want to get all text which resides inside those two keywords. Should i use regex? I want to take those two keywords as input.
It would be helpful if you give an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use Regex: `keyword1(.*?)keyword2`. PHP example:

```
preg_match_all('/'.$kwdOne.'(.*?)'.$kwdTwo.'/s', $str, $matches);
```

Read: [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 1):

As what Dor said, but the example of:

```
<?php
$keyword1 = "this";
$keyword2 = "this";
$str = "this is my string this";

preg_match("/$keyword1(.*)$keyword2/s",$str,$matches);

echo $matches[1];

?>
```

Outputs:

```
is my string
```

Comment: hi ... another question . if the text is multi line , will it work ?? i need the solution for multi line text too .

Comment: I've altered it with the 's' flag.. this will match multi line now

Comment: hi .. thanks for previous help . i am facing a real life problem here . i am trying to get some text from this page using simplehtmldom : http://laperuanavegana.wordpress.com/ my desired text is inside this two keywords "Ingredientes" and "Preparación:" but i think the regex is not working properly .here is my code . http://codepad.org/lyRVBhCz   would any one please check this code for bug ??